# Launch splash screen in Landscape mode for iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

Our universal application is in Landscape mode only. We need to add a splash screen for iPhone 4 & iPhone 5.

For iPhone 5 in Portrait we use `Default-568h@2x.png`. How to set a launch screen in Landscape for iPhone 5?

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624135/splash-launch-image-in-landscape-mode

Comment: I know you could name the Default.png file to different things in previous versions of xCode (pre-iPhone5) which would do landscape splash screens and what-not, but why not just design a landscape Default.png and rotate it the seem portrait (in terms of dimensions) but to a human eye it will obviously be turned, will this not simulate the same effect as just loading a splash screen that is landscape? Good luck with your solution, I wish I could be of more help! God bless!

Comment: Thanks Albert but i tried this also.not successed

Comment: Did you found the right answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to **Apple's Documentation** : [Providing Launch Images for Different Orientations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12)
,

Each orientation-specific launch image must include a special modifier string in its filename. The format for **orientation-specific launch image** filenames is as follows:

```
<basename><orientation_modifier><scale_modifier><device_modifier>.png
```

**Eg :**

```
1)    Default-Portrait.png
2)    Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png
3)    Default-Landscape.png
4)    Default-LandscapeLeft.png
5)    Default-LandscapeRight.png
```

**Note :** *These modifiers are supported for launch images used in iPad apps only.*

So you have to change your **Image** according to the **Orientation** for **iPhone 5**.

**Two ways to do that :**

> **1)** Rotating the Splash Image to 90 Degree.
>
> **2)** Inverting the Dimensions (320 * 480 -> 480 * 320).

Answer (score 2):

to provide a landscape launch image you must create the image.. and just rotate it 90 degrees in an external image editor

Answer (score 0):

Very simple
make design on splash screen in landscape mode .
and just make splash screen as you do in portrait .
user automatically make phone landscape when he/she see screen is in landscape :-)

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12), landscapes launch screens are supported for iPad only.

For iPhone and iPod Touch, you need to create a portrait launch screen that can be your 90°-oriented landscape launch screen. I would apply a clockwise rotation rather than a counter-clockwise rotation (ie so that on a desktop, you need to bend your head on the right to see the image with the correct orientation).

Answer (score -3):

use these macros in pch file

```
#if IS_iPAD
LaunchImage=iPad.png
else
LaunchImage=iPhone.png
```

Comment: `#define ... else ... `?? This does not even compile.