# Xcode5 has no landscape launch image slot for iPhone

Tags: xcode5, asset-catalog, launchimage

My app is for iPhone and in landscape mode only.  After updating to Xcode5 and using the asset catalog, I am unable to set launch images in the asset catalog because those slots are not available (see images below).  How can I make them visible?  This looks like a bug to me.

I tried following advice of another post by unchecking the iOS7 options, but that doesn't resolve the issue -- I still have no landscape mode slots.

[image: Image showing my project settings using landscape left/right orientation]

[image: Image showing asset catalog not having the option of landscape images]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per apples Guide lines iPhone dont have landscape Launch images. 
  Please have a look on this thread for more info and workaround. 
[splash (launch image) in landscape mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624135/splash-launch-image-in-landscape-mode)