# iPhone Launch Image Landscape

Tags: ios, landscape, launchimage

I am trying to add a launch image to my Universal landscape game. I am using the Asset Catalog. Here is how it looks like:

[image]

For the iPad everything is all right but on the iPhone no launch image appears.

Comment: possible duplicate of [splash (launch image) in landscape mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624135/splash-launch-image-in-landscape-mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people think that this is a bug, and have posted their finding in this thread [iPhone landscape-only no launch image for iOS7 R4 image asset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110583/iphone-landscape-only-no-launch-image-for-ios7-r4-image-asset) . You might want to try the solution in that thread.